# Encoding in Telnet-Client EL5(centos5)

Tags: character-encoding, telnet

I have a server(EL5) with telnet client.
wherever I connect, accented characters and other characters are not read correctly and output as "è" = "C(" , "à" = "C" , "°" = "B0" , etc ...
How can i resolve?
the system language is en_US.UTF-8 (i use Italian Keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

(Too big for a Comment.)

"°" = "B0"

B0 is the hex for degree sign in several encodings:  cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, geostd8, greek, hebrew, latin1, latin2, latin5, latin7

C2B0 is the hex encoding for degree sign in UTF-8.

I see no good way to connect the ends, especially since your 3 other examples do not follow this pattern.  Could you prove some more examples.  And leave them in words.